# Example of a "hybrid" Python module containing both compiled and interpreted code?

Tags: python

Can you recommend a well-structured Python module combining both compiled C code (e.g. using distutils) and interpreted source code?  I gather that "packages" can roll up interpreted modules and compiled modules, but I'm at a loss if it's possible to combine both compiled and interpreted sources into a single module.    Does such a thing exist?

If not, is The Right Thing (TM) to have a package with `from-import` statements loading the public symbols from separated compiled and interpreted submodules?

Comment: For an example, look at Python's own socket.py and _socket.so modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have one module with both Python and C.  Every .py file is a module, and C files are compiled and built into .so or .pyd files, each of which is a module.  You can import the compiled module into the Python file and use them together.

If you want some ultra-simple examples, you might like [A Whirlwind Excursion through Python C Extensions](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/whirlext.html).